# Has anyone been able to make physion passenger working under windows?

Tags: passenger

I am trying to use https://www.phusionpassenger.com  It says there that it is not supported in Windows. However, just out of curiousity and mauybe possiblity of less than 0, can it be made possible or has anyone had any luck? The video that he had seemed interesting. So just asking...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Phusion Passenger author here. The answer is no, unless someone is willing to pay us a very large sum of money.